# AngularJS ng-repeat apply css to whole list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm doing a image grid view galery. I'm using for that ng-repeat and CSS.
My code looks like:

```
<div class="grid-container" style="display:block;">
<ul class="rig columns-3" ng-repeat="element in elementsList track by $index">
    <li>
         <img ng-src='{{src_url}}' ng-click="routeTo('/')"/>            
    </li>                  
</ul>
</div>
```

Now I have css for changeit to a grid with 3 columns.
The problem is when I do statically 3x `<li>` the css works great and I have 3 images in a row.
But when I'm loading it with ng-repeat I have only 1 image per row.
It seems that css is applied before ng-repeat list is and somehow it doesn't make the grid for my images.

What should I do to make it right?

Comment: please share css and controller code as well

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet, you're actually repeating `<ul>` three times, not `<li>`.

Move ng-repeat to `<li>`, something like:

```
<ul class="rig columns-3">
    <li ng-repeat="element in elementsList track by $index">
         <img ng-src='{{src_url}}' ng-click="routeTo('/')"/>            
    </li>                  
</ul>
```

(also, are you sure you need `{{src_url}}` and not `{{element.src_url}}`?)